# Installing ubuntu next to windows 10, screen freezes after installing question

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, freeze

I got a new pc a couple of months ago. Today I wanted to try to install ubuntu next to windows 10. However my screen seems to freeze right after selecting for the option "installing ubuntu". I can also choose "try it out" before installing but then it freezes as well. It shows a logo from one of the manufacturers (gigabyte). And then a colored line green to purple enters the screen. And a couple of seconds later there is a disturbance lower in the screen as well and then the whole screen seems to have frozen.

I tried different images. Different image writing tools (balena and rufus). Different usb ports. I installed the same image on another laptop of mine just fine. So there is something with this PC that it just freezes. Or it's got to do with my screen somehow.

Are there any suggestions for what might be causing this? Any help greatly appreciated!

By the way it's the regular version. Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: What model Gigabyte, what video card/chip? Have you updated UEFI, updated SSD firmware (if SSD). Turned off fast boot, changed drives to AHCI in UEFI. And turned off Windows fast start up? Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Oke I managed to turn some settings to "legacy" and that fixed it for me. I saw somewhere else that perhaps turning some settings to "legacy" would fix it, and it did. It was after I toggled something called CSM or CMS (not sure anymore). So look for that if you're having the same problem.